# Is it possible python strings are not as inmutable as I had thought?

Tags: python, string

I was trying some recursive code in which I create a string outside the first call of my recursive function, and send that string as an argument to said first call. This string gets passed around a ton of times inside a recursive algorithm.

Inside this function, the string is mutated using `+=`. This function obviously gets called a lot as its recursive. I assumed each modification to the string wouldn't inadvertently affect the other function as `+=` should create a new instance of the string, but it seems that sometimes it does mutate it and affects other calls of my function.

[image]

I did some digging around (picture above) and found that when doing `+=` to a function sometimes it keeps its `id`, though I don't know if this confirms my suspicion.

Anyone have any idea of what could be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely a memory management optimization that keeps the same ID when you are extending the only reference to a string where available memory exists at the end of the string.  At some point the preallocated memory block get filled and a new ID needs to be assigned.

To confirm this, if you store a copy of `a` in a list, you'll see the id change at every iteration (because there is now more than one reference to the string):

```
a = ""
b = []
for i in range(30):
    a += "A"
    b.append(a)
    print(id(a))
```

Comment: If you make the loop bigger and count how many strings use the same ID, you will see that python is just allocating in 16-byte chunks, which is common.

Comment: It's changing every 8 allocations on my 64bit MacOS laptop. (could be different depending on the OS)

Comment: That's interesting. Also on a mac and seeing 16-byte chunks. Safe to say it's implementation dependent :).

Comment: I'm on Pyhton 3.7.  that could explain it as well